# how to select a parent in an older version of Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a function here that finds the sibling(answerfields) of the parent(li) then counts the child inputs.

```
$('#addAnswer').live('click', function(){
    var selected = $(this).parents('li').siblings('#answerFields').children('input').length;
    document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = selected;
});
```

How can i shorten this up using Jquery 1.5.2?

I have a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rayd360/bPp8a/).

Comment: this would you the length of input boxes .. what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: It's a bit wrong to have more than one element with the same id, by the way.

Comment: this code is very long and taks a lot of JQuery to find inputs that are so close. I would think there is something i am missing in JQuery to shorten this to one command like a .parent('li#answerFields'). and sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 0):

The only statement that seems appropriate to "shorten" is
    document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = selected;

which you can write in jQuery as

```
$('legend').html(selected);
```

Note that "live" has been deprecated in version 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Id must be unique, and so if there is one #answerFields element, you can directly use

`$("#answerFields input").length`

instead of

`$(this).parents('li').siblings('#answerFields').children('input').length;`

Answer (score 0):

There's just so much wrong here i'm not sure where to begin.

ID's must be unique, and by the looks of your code, your page has duplicate ID's.

`.parents("li")` should be `.closest("li")` unless you actually want to select all ancestor elements that are `li` elements instead of just the closest one.

To make this code *more* correct without requiring you to make the id's unique, you could use this:

```
$(this).closest("li").siblings('[id="answerFields"]').children('input').length;
```

As far as making it smaller, that is about as small as it's going to get.

using `.live()` on an element with an ID seems odd too. There's only one valid element that contains that id, why not just bind to that element when it is created?